# Is it possible to read structured data from a CSV in Genexus?

Tags: genexus

Genexus has the ExcelDocument data type that allows you to read data in a tabular way from an excel file, specifying rows and columns. Is there a way to do the same with a csv file? I can open it and read it like a normal txt, but a structure would be more effective

Answer (score 3):

As ealmeida explained you can use the [Delimited ASCII files functions](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?8364,Delimited%20ASCII%20files%20functions).

Below you can see an example on how to code both read and write operations.

**ASCII File sample**

```
1,"Jane Doe",1955-05-21
2,"John Smith",1991-10-15
3,"William Shakespeare",2005-11-30
```

**Setup variables with parameters**

```
&FullFileName = !'Datos.txt'
&RecordLength = 50
&FieldsDelimiter = !','
&StringDelimiter = !'"'
&DateFormat = !'ymd'
&DateSeparator = !'-'
```

**To read Delimited ASCII**

```
&ErrorNbr = DFROpen(&FullFileName, &RecordLength, &FieldsDelimiter, &StringDelimiter)
do while DFRNext() = 0
    &ErrorNbr = DFRGNum(&PersonNumber)
    &ErrorNbr = DFRGTxt(&PersonName)
    &ErrorNbr = DFRGDate(&PersonDOB, &DateFormat, &DateSeparator)
enddo
&ErrorNbr = DFRClose()
```

**To write Delimited ASCII**

```
&ErrorNbr = DFROpen(&FullFileName, &RecordLength, &FieldsDelimiter, &StringDelimiter)
for each Person
    &ErrorNbr = DFWPNum(PersonNumber, 0)
    &ErrorNbr = DFWPTxt(PersonName)
    &ErrorNbr = DFWPDate(PersonDOB, &DateFormat, &DateSeparator)
    &ErrorNbr = DFWNext()
endfor
&ErrorNbr = DFWClose()
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's posible, using [Delimited ASCII files functions](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?8364,Delimited%20ASCII%20files%20functions)

Comment: Do you have an example of use? I am trying to implement it but it is as if at each "next" it only reads the first column

Comment: Some simple (and old) examples, how to read an write using this functions. 
 http://library.gxtechnical.com/gxdl/pub/GeneXus/Java/Docum/Manuals/7.0/Java70En14.htm